# How to create customised vertex without creating the graph.?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, tinkerpop

I need to make an object of vertex in apache.tinkerpop for unit testing without creating an actual graph . Basically , I see no point to create an actual vertex in graph database.

I read about detached vertex , but not sure how to use it . Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DetachedVertex` class utilizes a builder pattern to instantiate instances - see [javadocs](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/structure/util/detached/DetachedVertex.Builder.html). Use the static `build()` method to create a `Builder` instance and then set its properties before calling `create()` to instantiate an instance:

```
Vertex v = DetachedVertex.build().setId(1).setLabel('person').create();
```

In the above example, we create a `Vertex` with a unique identifier and label but no properties. Adding properties is accomplished using the `addProperty() method which takes a`DetachedVertexProperty`- see [javadoc][2]. Like`DetachedVertex`, the`DetachedVertexProperty` uses a builder pattern, therefore adding properties is like:

```
Vertex v = DetachedVertex.build().setId(1).setLabel('person').
               addProperty(DetachedVertexProperty.build().                                    
                                                  setId(10).setLabel('name').
                                                  setValue('marko').create()).
               create();
```